# How to create custom master page in visual studio for SharePoint hosted app

Tags: document-library, master-page, custom-masterpage, list-form, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to create master page for my SharePoint hosted app and apply it to all pages. please suggest the help

Comment: SharePoint hosted or Provider hosted?

Comment: Sharepoint hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done the way we used to do it with Farm or Sandboxed solution.

Create a module, add your Master page to it and change the Url of the File element to be _catalogs/masterpage and reference this master page in your pages

Comment: but how we can apply the same for list

Comment: It will not be applicable for Allitems.aspx or NewForm.aspx

Comment: So How to apply to those pages

Comment: I am not really sure if this is doable, i did some googling and everyone says that SharePoint hosted apps follow the the theme of the hosted app, so you can provision the master page to the hosted app and change the master page for the hosted app which will reflect on the app web of the SharePoint Hosted App

Comment: But how to change master page. We can't use Designer for this. So how this will works?

Comment: Changing the master page for the hosted app can be either done from the UI (Settings -> Master Page -> and choose Backend Master Page)

You can also do it using PowerShell or through CSOM from your app

Comment: Once we deploye app and after that the changes make form UI will reflects only for that session.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment, the only change from the UI is changing the master page in the host web which will not affect any code or changes you did in the app web

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37326/discussion-between-mrunal-shidurkar-and-haitham-shaddad).